# User-provided environment variable within docker CMD

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I have successfully pushed my docker image to the swisscom app cloud (similar to this example: https://ict.swisscom.ch/2016/05/docker-and-cloudfoundry/).

Now I would like to use a user-provided environment variable within my docker CMD. Something like this:

```
ADD target/app.jar app.jar
CMD java -jar app.jar -S $USER_PROVIDED_ENV_VARIABLE
```

I also tried system-provided environment variables:

```
ADD target/app.jar app.jar
CMD java -jar app.jar -S $VCAP_APPLICATION
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Dockerfile is built like that, you'll simply need to pass the `-e` flag when running the image.

**Example Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.10
ENV MY_VAR "default value" # Optional - set a default value.
CMD echo $MY_VAR
```

**Build the image:**

```
docker build -t my_image .
```

**Run a container from the image:**

```
docker run -e MY_VAR="my value here" my_image
```

Comment: Probably want to suggest `ENV MY_VAR=default` so you have an explicit default value

Comment: Yep. Wasn't feeling greedy enough to post an answer with that included :)